# How do I add a hyperlink in a card to a document on my server?

Tags: trello, links

How do I add a hyperlink in a card to a document on my server? For document version management, I need the members to work on the document saved in my local server.  How do I create a link to my server?

Comment: Please note that this site is for questions about all kinds of web applications, not just Trello. You need to tag your question accordingly so that the people who can answer can find your question.

Answer (score 1):

The answer depends upon what kind of network you have.

The link success your users will have will be determined by the permissions they each have as well as their connectivity to the server.

Meaning, if a user is not connected directly to your server or does not have access to the file location, they will receive an error message.

With that in mind, all you need to do is provide the link in a Card description.

For a MS Windows network, you would use the "UNC" version of the file location.

Example:

Latest file: \\servername\path\folder\subfolder\file

For a cleaner look, you can use Markup in the card description

Example:

To edit the current version of the file, click here.

Will look like:
To edit the current version of the file, [click here]

If your filename includes spaces, enclose the entire link in quotes ("\server.....ext")